# Hibernate orphan-removal

Tags: java, hibernate

The Question is asked many times in this forum, but nothing seems to be similar to problem I am facing.So posting this Question.

I have a Class A, Class B, Class C and Class D. Class D has a Primary Key and 3 Foreign Key from A, B and C.(Included All 3 in hashCode and equals)

Now Class A contains Set of Class D OnetoMany mapping (mappedby=A,orphan-removal=true). In my code

```
oldSetofD.retainAll(newSetofD);
oldSetofD.addAll(newSetofD);
objA.setDobjSet(oldSetofD);
```

Now when I am trying to save objA

```
session.saveOrUpdate(objA);
```

I want the orphan values of D in database to be removed afer this.But this is not happening.What is the mistake I am making.

Comment: remove orphan values separately before saving the object

Comment: By separately you mean doing something like oldSetofD.remove(removeSetofD)

Comment: might be yes . if u cannot achieve something in single-process. split the process and do :)

Comment: I have large amount of data, and I don't want it to be Spilt in multiple process.Also,Why Orphan-Removal is not working. What is the issue with that?